# Disable Window buttons Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im creating a tkinter program and was wondering if you could disable the buttons on the top bar of the window. 
So far I have tried

```
menu.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", button_pressed)
menu.protocol("WM_MINIMIZE_WINDOW", button_pressed)

def button_pressed():
    pass
```

and

```
menu.overrideredirect(1)
```

Problem 1:

In the first one, the minimize button still makes the window dissapear, as im not sure the `WM_MINIMIZE_WINDOW` is correct. However, the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` works.

Problem 2:

using `menu.overrideredirect(1)` means that I cannot make the window fullscreen and that is one of the main features of my program.

Probably the first one would be better so what is the correct way to use it?

If either of these methods are not possible, let me know a possible way to disable the buttons!

Comment: There is no `WM_MINIMIZE_WINDOW', read up on [wm protocol](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M58)

Comment: @stovfl so what is the correct term?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Seems your only solution is to remove, `overrideredirect`, the whole window decoration. In general this is Window Manager dependant, on *Windows* there may be a `win32com` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this @Legacy Coding:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thats good but how can I toggle fullscreen with this solution?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I imagine increasing the screen height and adding a width parameter should help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: @adamfitzpatrick: This gives: `NameError: name 'FALSE' is not defined`

Comment: @LegacyCoding ***how can I toggle fullscreen***: Place a own `[ ]` minimize Button where you can bind a callback.